# Скрыть все bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, popover

Вывожу `popover` в таблице в каждой строке, когда открываю следующий `popover` предыдущий закрывается, но если повторно хочу открыть тот `popover` который закрылся, то это получается сделать только при втором клике на строке в таблице, кто подскажет как сделать так чтобы открывался `popover` при повторном его открытии одним кликом а не двумя.
Нашел еще один пример, добавил в него `else`

```
$(document).ready(function () {

                $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
                    //Установление направления отображения popover
                    placement: 'top',
                    container: 'body'
                });

                $('body').on('click', function (e) {
                    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {

                        if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 &&
                                $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
                            $(this).popover('hide');
                        } else {
                            $(this).popover('show');
                        }
                    });
                });
});
```

Но сейчас последний `popover` который открыт, могу закрыть только при нажатии на 
шапку таблицы, а хотелось бы чтобы закрывалось при втором нажатии на строку таблицы вызывающую `popover`, может кто знает чем помочь?